# customize and control devtools not working in Canary Version 49.0.2574.0 (64-bit)

Tags: google-chrome

I've just installed Canary and opening DevTools they appear docked to the right so I thought I'd just dock them to the bottom of the screen but the three-vertical-dots menu to the left of the X don't work, I get a tooltip: 'Customize and control DevTools' but I can left-click to my heart's content and nothing will happen.

The ordinary version of the Chrome browser works fine.

I'm on Windows 7, 64bit.

any ideas anyone?

Comment: Report the bug on https://crbug.com, rollback to the previous version, wait for the fix.

Comment: I have the same problem.

But there is a keyboard shortcut to change between "bottom of the screen" and "right on the screen".
Ctrl + Shift + D for Windows and Cmd + Shift + D for Mac.

I can't find a shortcut the third option.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/iterate/inspect-styles/shortcuts#global-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: @Marian07: for me, those keyboard shortcuts switch back and forth between the last two 'locations'.  For example, if Dev Tools is on the "Dock to bottom" and I 'manually' select "Undock into separate window"... and then use the keyboard shortcut, Dev Tools toggles between 'bottom' and 'undock'.  For what it's worth.